# Firebase Notifications - Mandar notificaciones cuando un evento ocurra

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification

Tengo una app que usa los servicios de firebase. Quiero que cuando lea de la base de datos y la aplicación este en segundo plano me muestre una notificación cuando **TODOS** los datos estén leídos.

**Código del evento de escucha**

```
 databaseReference.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {

            Viaje viaje = dataSnapshot.getValue(Viaje.class);

            sendNotificationOfTripFound(); //esta funcion es la que quiero crear
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildChanged(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildRemoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildMoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

He intentado con Cloud Messaging pero no se como decirle que el evento es:

> addChildEventListener

Existe alguna manera de lograr lo que necesito?

Comment: ¿Esta linea es Asincronica? Viaje viaje = dataSnapshot.getValue(Viaje.class);

Comment: Esa línea eata dentro un evento de escucha.. que es el onChildAdded... mi duda en general es como puedo mandar notificaciones cuando un nuevo viaje es publicado desde firebase hacia mi app si esta en segundo plano.

Comment: Mmm pues parece que estuvieras viendo el problema desde el ángulo incorrecto, lo que yo haría es crear un tema 'viajes' en fire base y suscribir la app a ese tema, y cada vez que se publique un nuevo viaje automáticamente Firebase notifica a la app

Comment: como haria eso? pudiera ser una respuesta a mi problema te agradeceria que me dijeras como

Comment: No tienes realizado nada acerca de como enviar y recibir las notificaciones? @AlexRivas

Comment: no @Jorgesys no tengo idea de como se hace y estaba leyendo que existen canales tambien para eso? como puedo crear varios canales en fireabase y que mande notificaciones cuando exista un nuevo viaje en la base de datos?